# Microsoft Auth Library (MSAL) Seems to Interfere with Custom RoleProvider and cacheRolesInCookie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, azure-ad-msal

After incorporating the code from this project, https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect, into my application so I can access the MS Graph APIs, it seemed to get stuck in a loop trying to acquire the token.

After some trial and error and educated guesses, I discovered that setting cacheRolesInCookie="false" for my custom RoleProvider in Web.Config solved the problem.

The developer of the ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect sample was able to recreate the problem, but suggested that it may be an issue with the asp.net System.Web.Security code.   See this issue for more details:  https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapp-openidconnect/issues/41

Right now turning off the role provider cookie cache works OK for my app, but I would be interested in understanding why a custom RoleProvider caching roles in a cookie would interfere with the MS Graph Authentication. I did try changing some of the other RoleProvider cookie settings, like changing the cookie name, but it didn't seem to make any difference.

If nothing else this might save someone else the effort of discovering this issue.

Thanks

Note:  This is an asp.net app, .net framework 4.7.2 (not aspnetcore).  Unfortunately, I don't have the resources to switch to core.